# Isoperimetry on $[0, 1]^n$ w.r.t $\ell_p$ distance, with $p \in [1,\infty]$

Tags: pr.probability, measure-concentration, geometric-probability, isoperimetric-problems

Let $A$ be a measurable subset of the metric space $\mathcal X = ([0, 1]^n,\ell_p)$ with $1 \le p \le \infty$, and define its $\varepsilon$-blowup by $A^\varepsilon:=\{x \in \mathcal X \mid \|x-a\|_p \le \epsilon\text{ for some }a \in A\}$.

## Question

- If $\operatorname{vol}(A) > 0$, what is a good lower bound on $\operatorname{vol}(A^\epsilon)$ ?
- Same question with $\operatorname{vol}(A) \ge 1/2$.

**N.B.:** I'm mostly interested in the cases $p \in \{1,2,\infty\}$.

Comment: It appears that the euclidean case $p=2$ is solved by (1.1) of http://www-users.math.umn.edu/~bobko001/papers/2010_JMS-165_Conc.on.the.cube.pdf

Comment: It's the first time I see "blow-up" used in this sense.

Answer (score 1):

I managed to piece together a solution to my problem by reading the first page of this paper http://www-users.math.umn.edu/~bobko001/papers/2010_JMS-165_Conc.on.the.cube.pdf.

I'll only handle the euclidean case $p=2$, as the other cases will follow by equivalence of $\ell_p$-norms (it's possible this "delegation procedure" is not very optimal for...).

So, consider the function $T:\mathbb R^n \rightarrow [0, 1]^n$ defined by $T(z_1,\ldots,z_n)=(\Phi(z_1),\ldots,\Phi(z_n))$ where $\Phi$ is the standard Gaussian CDF. It's easy to see that $u_n=\gamma_n \circ T^{-1}$. We will take for granted that $\Phi$ (and therefore $T$) is $(2\pi)^{-1/2}$-Lipschitz continuous.

Let $A$ be a measurable subset of $[0,1]^n$ and let $B:=T^{-1}A$. Lipschitzness of $T$ implies $A^\varepsilon \supseteq B^{\varepsilon\sqrt{2\pi}}$, and so $u_n(A^\varepsilon) \ge \gamma_n(B^{\varepsilon\sqrt{2\pi}})$. Now, by Gaussian Isoperimetry,
$$
u_n(A^\varepsilon) \ge \gamma_n(B^{\varepsilon\sqrt{2\pi}}) \ge \Phi^{-1}(\gamma_n(B)+\varepsilon\sqrt{2\pi}) = \Phi^{-1}(u_n(A)+\varepsilon\sqrt{2\pi})
$$